# defined a string as the tab name, how can I use it?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I defined fname as the tab name and I want to change the figure data from current tab. but when I use fname as shown below, nothing happens.

```
Sub paste_and_update_data()

'
' paste_and_update_data Macro
'
Dim fname As String
fname = ActiveSheet.Name


'MsgBox fname

'    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='fname'!$D$4:$D$8"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "='fname'!$F$4:$F$8"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Values = "='fname'!$h$4:$h$8"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *concatenate* variables into strings before passing them to properties or methods.

For example:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "='" & fname & "'!$D$4:$D$8"
```

Comment: Thanks very much!!!!